# secure textfield in nstableview

Tags: xcode, security, textbox, nstableview

first of all lets say that i searched quite a bit for an answer to this and wasnt able to find one.

i have a nstableview, with 5 columns, all with text field cells. one of these columns is a password column. i would like taht this column hides the typed chars. how can that be done? the only way i found by googeling was to insert a "image and text cell view", delete the picture and the textbox and enter a secure textbox. but i dont like this option because the password column would look different then the Others and if possible i would like to stay with the default appearance of a normal nstableview.

is this possible? if yes, how?

thanks!

Igor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your .xib file

In your TableView select the Text Cell you want to change to a "password" style

Go to Identity Inspector

In "Class" field replace NSTextFieldCell with NSSecureTextFieldCell

That's it :)